# Spring Boot - MockMvc result null for GET (Cucumber)

Tags: java, spring, cucumber, mockmvc

I am running into an issue when trying to create a mockMvc `get` request, I receive a null result when requesting to get a JSON object. I have it that I can create a `post` fine, but struggling to receive data when invoking a GET endpoint in my controller.

`AddressStepDefs.java`

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@Transactional
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
/**
 * Address Step Definition class to execute Scenario(s) contained in Address.feature
 * @author Lewis Jones
 *
 */
public class AddressStepDefs {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private ResultActions result;

    @Autowired
    @MockBean
    private AddressRepository addressRepo;

    /**
     * Build the Controller under test
     */
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new AddressController()).build(); 
    }

    /**
     * Set the mock server up
     */
    @Before
    public void serverSetup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    /**
     * Build the WebApplicationContext
     */
    @Given("The server is up and running")
    public void the_server_is_up_and_running() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @When("I request to view an Address with id {int} at {string}")
    public void i_request_to_view_an_Address_with_id_at(Integer id, String request) throws Exception {
        /** Build a GET request using mockMvc **/
        result = this.mockMvc.perform(get(request + id).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }

    @Then("the response code should be OK {int} and the resulting Address object json should be:")
    public void the_response_code_should_be_OK_and_the_resulting_Address_object_json_should_be(Integer responseCode, String json) throws Exception {
        result.andExpect(status().is(responseCode));
        result.andExpect(content().string(json));
    }
```

- The Controller endpoint and the request is fine.
- There is data in the database.
- It works WITHOUT the `@MockBean`, but then my `post` actually inserts data into the database. (Which isn't what I want)
- I have tried to `@InjectMocks`, no luck.

Where am I going wrong? Do I have the correct annotations?

Comment: You mocked your AddressRepository, fine. Then what? Your mocked AddressRepository will not magicaly return an `Address` matching your serialized json. Somehow, you have to give instructions to your mocked repository. What it has to do when its findById method is invoked? You'll find a lot of tutorials on internet that will explain better than me how to use mockito

Comment: @Imaguest The `addressRepo.findById` is used once `this.mockMvc.perform(get(request + id)` is called. This a controller method that invokes the repo method.. As mentioned, as soon I remove the `@MockBean` the result returns correctly, but then it's not mocked.

Comment: I'm affraid using @Autowired and @MockBean together is mistake. You should describe mock beahaviour of addressRepo somehow - like `Mockito.when(addressRepo.count()).thenReturn(123L);`

Comment: Yes i know that.. When you don't mock your repository, the original implementation is executed. But if you mock your repository, using mockito, and you don't provide instructions on the "new method implementation", it will not work. basically is just saying: when this method is called (with this arguments) then return something. That's it. But you've missed this point and it's basics when using mockito. That's why you should learn how to use it.

Comment: @lojza this could be a way of approaching it, but then my REST endpoint(s) aren't tested? I will be just testing the repo functionality and not the mappings?

Comment: @imaguest okay, i will look into mockito a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

By mocking your bean, you'll get all its results as null.

You have 2 options,

1. You continue to mock but you define behaviors using when/then
2. You spy your bean: then it will do "the same" as normal and you can just stub the method you don't want.

Comment: But I do receive a result in another test case (in the same class), using `this.mockMvc.perform(post(request)` with a json object defined in a `.feature` file? Is it different for `get` and `post`?

Comment: In each test case you can write something different like:
when(addressRepo.foo(anyString()).thenReturn("what you want to be mocked");
or even
when(addressRepo.foo(anyString()).thenCallRealMethod();